# Why is this JQuery 'keyup' function not populating a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count

I am attempting to display the current character count as the user is typing in a textarea.

I have this simple form:

```
<div id="testimonialCount"></div>

<form data-role="form" id="testimonialForm" name="tesitmonialForm">
      <label for="testimonial">Testimonial </label>
      <textarea  name="testimonial" id="testimonial" placeholder="Enter your testimonial (1000 word limit)"></textarea>
</form>
```

and the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#testimonial").on('keyup', function(e){
        var count = (this).val().length;
        $("#testimonialCount").html("<p>- Character count:" + count + "</p>");
    });

});
```

Currently nothing is displaying in the `testimonialCount` div. Why is this?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksq6K/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `keyup` function you are missing `$` while selecting the element.

use this

```
var count = $(this).val().length;
```

instead of

```
var count = (this).val().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 

$("#testimonial").on('keyup', function(e){
    var count= $(this).val().length;


    $("#testimonialCount").html("<p>- Character count:" + count + "</p>");
});
```

Comment: you should probably edit your answer and explain that you added the `$` to the `(this)`, because it took me a few minutes to figure out what you've changed.